# CSS !important not taking precedence?

Tags: css

I have the following dom structure:

```
<div class="ui-tabs">
<ul>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
         <a href="#">Text</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS markup:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-state-active {
background: #084;
color: #E6EFEA !important;
}

a:link {
color: #00C;
}
```

I cannot get the first color (E6EFEA) to take precedence. I've tried it on FireFox and Chrome, Chrome even shows the a:link property scratched out ... as if some other color is taking precedence, but still renders blue (00C). Just to make sure I've taken out every other #00C refeence in the CSS file. Any ideas?

I've also put up a crude example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/avazu/edit).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`!important` only works when the attribute is being applied to the same element.  In this case you are applying it to the `<a>` element's parent, and it *is* being set there (throw some text outside of the `<a>` to convince yourself).

If you want to override the color of the `<a>` element itself, your CSS rule will have to apply to the `<a>`, not an ancestor.

Comment: Exactly what i meant to say! Good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-tabs .ui-state-active a:link {
color: #E6EFEA !important;
}
```

This should do the deed.

You need to set your color on the a tag not the .ui-state-active class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify also :link

```
.ui-tabs .ui-state-active:link {
    background: #084;
    color: #E6EFEA !important;
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this won't work as .ui-state-active is the parent and is not a <a> tag.

Comment: ops sorry for mistyping. I forgot an 'a' like jensen solution

Answer (score 0):

In this way you color the dot of the list...

try this code:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-state-active a {
    background: #084;
    color: #E6EFEA;
}
```